# Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, ftp, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-7.5, iis-8.5

I have just set up a FTP server in IIS 8.5 on my  Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.

With FileZilla when I try connect to the local IP (10.0.0.4) with my username and password on port 21, it will connect just fine, But when I try to connect on the external IP I get this error

> Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server
>   address instead

Here is the full log

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to 191.23x.xx.111:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to 191.23x.xx.111:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Where it hangs on

> Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.

for a bit of time before it fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the external IP of your server to have passive mode work.

In IIS: (step 5 for passive mode, other are for active mode)

> How to configure the global firewall settings for the FTP service
>
> 1.Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager:
>
> •If you are using Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2:
>
> •On the taskbar, click
>   Server Manager, click Tools, and then click Internet Information
>   Services (IIS) Manager.
>
> 2.In the Connections pane, click the server name.
>
> 3.In the Home pane, double-click the FTP Firewall Support feature.
>
> 4.In the Data Channel Port Range box, use one of the following options to enter a port range for passive data channel connections:
>
> •Use [low
>   port]-[high port] for a port range, where each port must be between
>   1025 and 65535. For example, 5000-6000.
>
> •Use "0-0" to configure the
>   FTP server to use the Windows TCP/IP ephemeral port range.
>
> 5.In the External IP Address of Firewall box, type the IPv4 address of the Internet-facing network adapter of your firewall.
>
> 6.In the Actions pane, click Apply.

If it's not there, you need to active FTP Extension.

> Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2
>
> 1.On the taskbar, click Server Manager.
>
> 2.In Server Manager, click the Manage menu, and then click Add Roles and Features.
>
> 3.In the Add Roles and Features wizard, click Next. Select the installation type and click Next. Select the destination server and
>   click Next.
>
> 4.On the Server Roles page, expand Web Server (IIS), and then select FTP Server.
>
> Note: To support ASP.Membership authentication or IIS Manager
>   authentication for the FTP service, you will need to select FTP
>   Extensibility, in addition to FTP Service.
>
> 5.Click Next, and then on the Select features page, click Next again.
>
> 6.On the Confirm installation selections page, click Install.
>
> 7.On the Results page, click Close.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use vsftpd, set

```
    pasv_min_port=21000
    pasv_max_port=21999
```

in vsftpd.conf file.

2. Open that port range in your network console panel of your VPS/Cloud provider.

This solve my same error.